# It is possible to get an IntPtr from an int[] array?

Tags: c#, int, intptr, emgucv, stride

Greetings.

In C#: If I have an int[] array declared like this

```
int[] array = new array[size];
```

there is an way to get the IntPtr from this array?

The thing is that I'm using the EmguCV framework, and there is an constructor to create an image which takes an IntPtr to the pixel data, in order to build an image from an array (int[]).

```
Image<Gray,Int32> result = new Image<Gray,int>(bitmap.Width,bitmap.Height,stride,"**array.toPointer??**");
```

By the way if someone could told me how to calculate the stride, that would be  great.

Comment: C#.Sorry, I forgot to mention

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to do this without unsafe code using `GCHandle`.  Here is a sample:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned);
try
{
    IntPtr pointer = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
}
finally
{
    if (handle.IsAllocated)
    {
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any way to go the other way around without copying data?

Comment: This isn't copying the data.  It is telling the GC that you want a pointer to a managed object and don't move it on me (like when a collection happens).

Comment: I mean is it possible to create a managed array without copying the unmanaged data

Comment: This is definitely how Microsoft does it.

Comment: You don't need the `handle.IsAllocated` check, a pinned handle will remain allocated until `Free`d and if the constructor returned it will always have been allocated

Answer (score 10):

Use unsafe code, like this:

```
unsafe
{
  fixed (int* pArray = array)
  {
    IntPtr intPtr = new IntPtr((void *) pArray);
  }
}
```

Comment: And of course note that intPtr only points to the array *while control is in the fixed block*. Once you leave the fixed block the garbage collector is free to move pArray around in memory again and the intPtr could therefore be pointing to garbage.

Comment: Well, good thing this `intPtr` is only visible inside the fixed block.

Comment: Often times you want to pass the pointer to some unmanaged code, where you are going to copy the memory anyway. In those cases this is the correct solution.