# Marshall double[] to IntPtr in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, marshalling, intptr

I am trying to convert double[] to IntPtr in C#. Here is the data I am going to convert:

```
double[] rotX = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
double[] rotY = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
double[] rotZ = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
```

Here is the function I am going to feed in the IntPtr, which is converted from the array above:

```
SetRotationDirection(IntPtr rotX, IntPtr rotY, IntPtr rotZ);
```

How should I do the job?

Comment: possible duplicate of [It is possible to get an IntPtr from an int\[\] array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238049/it-is-possible-to-get-an-intptr-from-an-int-array)

Comment: how do you like your double to be rounded to integer?

Comment: @rajeem_cariazo: `IntPtr` is just a type in C# that allows you to store pointer in an integer. And, yes it also works on 64 bit. The IntPtr will receive the pointer to the memory, not the array values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

/* ... */

double[] rotX = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
double[] rotY = { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
double[] rotZ = { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };

var gchX = default(GCHandle);
var gchY = default(GCHandle);
var gchZ = default(GCHandle);

try
{
    gchX = GCHandle.Alloc(rotX, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    gchY = GCHandle.Alloc(rotY, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    gchZ = GCHandle.Alloc(rotZ, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    SetRotationDirection(
        gchX.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
        gchY.AddrOfPinnedObject(),
        gchZ.AddrOfPinnedObject());
}
finally
{
    if(gchX.IsAllocated) gchX.Free();
    if(gchY.IsAllocated) gchY.Free();
    if(gchZ.IsAllocated) gchZ.Free();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem` and `Marshal.Copy`:

```
double[] d = new double[] {1,2,3,4,5 };
IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeof(double)*d.Length);
Marshal.Copy(d, 0, p, d.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

IntPtr represent a platform specific integer. It's size is either 4 or 8 bytes depending on the target platform bitness.

How would you like to convert a double to an integer? you should expect data truncation.

Comment: The op wants to convert a *pointer* to a double to a 64 bit integer. That should work without truncation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var a = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(rotX[i]));
  var b = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(rotY[i]));
  var c = new IntPtr(Convert.ToInt32(rotZ[i]));
  SetRotationDirection(a, b, c);
}
```